# Inserting html into php using echo

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently developing web leaderboards for a Minecraft server and I've run into an issue.
Here's my code that works:

```
<?php
      while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
        echo
        "<tr>
          <td><a href='http://cravatar.eu/avatar/$row[UUID]/64.png'>$row[UUID]</a></td>
          <td>{$row["KILLS"]}</td>
          <td>{$row["DEATHS"]}</td>
        </tr>\n";
      }
    ?>
```

So I'm trying to make it instead of a clickable UUID make it the actual image. In order to do that it needs to be: (http://cravatar.eu/avatar/uuid/64.png) I've tried to use the img tag but I get an issue. I'm extremely new to php so if you can "dumb" down your answer that'd be great.

EDIT: I got it semi working! I used ($uuid = $row['UUID'];) then added the variable in the link. Thank you to everyone who suggested stuff!

Comment: I tried doing (<td><a href='http://cravatar.eu/avatar/$row[UUID]/64.png'><img src="http://cravatar.eu/avatar/Notch/64.png"</a></td>) but towards the end it starts a informative tag. @Nordenheim

Comment: Use the `{$row['UUID']}` syntax in the first `<td>` like you do in the last two.

Comment: @iVersion, do you have a closing tag on the img?  That's not valid HTML as it's written in the comment.

Comment: You need to make sure that contents of `$row["UUID"]` is vaild for an url. But it looks as if it is simply a nickname of an avatar so probably ok. Secondly, you must use the correct syntax for printing a variable within a string, as Kenney has pointed out. Last but not least, make sure your use of quote and doublequote doesnt get mixed up.. For instance, use single-quote for array-'names' and double quotes to encapsulate the string youre printing out

Comment: @Devon When testing that method I did add a closing img tag.
The $row["UUID"] should print out the UUID of the player which is fine for the website I'm using. Can you explain using the correct syntax for print a variable more?

Answer (score -1):

After correcting some mistakes, I have two ways that i would suggest for you to try

**1st way is**

```
<?php

      while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
        echo
        '<tr>
          <td><img src="http://cravatar.eu/avatar/64.png"/></td>
          <td>'.$row["KILLS"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["DEATHS"].'</td>
        </tr>\n;';
      }
?>
```

**And the 2nd way is**

```
<?php do { ?>


<tr>
  <td><img src="http://cravatar.eu/avatar/64.png"/><?php //echo $row['UUID']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row["KILLS"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row["DEATHS"]; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php  } while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not really an answer to the problem, just a different way of doing both the loop and the output.  Probably just going to confuse them, plus you have an error.

Comment: I have edited the answer and now it will display the image instead of the link @Devon

Comment: 1st method works just I need the avatar to update based on their stats. 
2nd method also works but it duplicates the table (https://gyazo.com/f2f7d95bd5259c844fb0981a5a0fd242)
@OmariOmosa

Comment: is `<?php echo $row['UUID']; ?>` code representing their stats?

Comment: The **second way** is the most sure way. It means you have two results. The **first way**, i have tried it in some scenario and in most of the scenario it displays one less. e.g. instead of displaying 5 it displays 4. instead of displaying 2 i displays 1,.   Lets try to do this @iVersion .Take this code `<?php echo $row['UUID']; ?>` as is to the **second code** that you say it is duplicating the table and try to fix it on the image whereby it keeps changing and see if it works

Comment: You use while, or do when you want to repeat a region .If you don't want to repeat a region you remove it and query the specific row that you want.